# Predator-Prey Modelling in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, modeling

I have a Predator-Prey Model:

```
dR/dt = λR - aRF
dF/dt = -μF + bRF
```

Where `λ` and `μ` are growth rates of rabbits (`R`) and foxes (`F`) respectively, treated in isolation. `a` is the predation rate of foxes on rabbits, and `b` is the growth rate of popluation of foxes through predation on rabbits.

So far I have the following code, but I've really confused myself, where is my model going wrong?

```
function PredPrey   
    lambda = 0.1; % Lambda = Reproduction rate of rabbits   
    mu = 0.15;    % Mu = Death rate of foxes    
    a = 0.005;    % a = Rate of rabbits caught per fox   
    b = 0.002;    % b = foxes born per rabbit caught

    N = 3;

    R = zeros(1,N);
    F = zeros(1,N);
    R(1) = 100;
    F(1) = 10;
    for n = 2:N
        R(n) = R(n-1) + lambda*R(n-1) - a*R(n-1)*F(n-1);
        F(n) = F(n-1) - mu*F(n-1) + b*a*R(n-1)*F(n-1);        
    end
    Xvals = 1:N;
    plot(Xvals,R,'b',Xvals,F,'r')        
end
```

Comment: The "foxes born per rabbit caught" term differs in your stated model and your code. In the model, you use `+bRF`, in the code you use `+abRF`. The correct choice depends on what this term represents. Other than that, please provide a clear example of what you *expect* as results vs what your *actually get*, because the implementation seems okay.

Comment: The bRF term looks suspicious. The more rabbits you have, the more foxes in the next generation, but according to this term, if you had a million foxes and one rabbit, you would have a hundred thousand or so foxes in the next generation. That can't be right.

Comment: I think that was it, thanks @Wolfie

Comment: If this was a typo and your problem can no longer be reproduced, you could consider removing the question. Otherwise look at P.Kein's answer and see if that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have a system of odes which needs tools like ode45 to handle. I suggest you to take a look at

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html

Moreover, you may use

```
function f = predPrey(t,x)

f = zeros(2,1);

% x(1) represents the number of rabbits
% x(2) represents the number of foxes

% Model's parameters
a = 0.01
b = 0.02
c = 0.03
d = 0.04    

f(1) = a*x(1) - b*x(1)*x(2);
f(2) = -c*x(2) + d*x(1)*x(2);

end
```

with the following command:

```
[time,valx] = ode45(@(t,x) predPrey(t,x),[0,5],[200,100]);
```

to solve the system for time t = 0 to t = 5 with the initial population of 200 rabbits and 100 foxes.

Note that

```
rabbit = valx(:,1)
fox = valx(:,2)
```